# 100% height inner table

Tags: html-table, html-email

I'm sending multiple emails. Part of their shared layout requires a white and yellow design on the left hand side. table1 does not have a fixed height as there will be different content depending on the email being sent. How can I get table2 to completely fill out height-wise? I'm using third party software to generate the html, so "fancy" inline CSS is a no-go.

```
<table name="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table height="100%" name="table2">
        <tr>
          <td height="100%" width="10px" bgcolor="white"></td>
          <td height="100%" width="30px" bgcolor="yellow"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      text that can so on and on and on...</br>
      more text</br>
      even more.</br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: cant you use inline css?

Comment: Nope. This is html generated from third party software which doesn't let you manually add in html/css. It just lets you add "table" objects etc.

Comment: within the table you can place inline css or is it filtered?

Comment: Its not a case of it getting filtered out, its that the software won't even let you type in the inline css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stretch the whole height why dont you loose table 2 and do something like:

```
<table name="table1">
  <tr> 
    <td width="10px" bgcolor="white"></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="yellow"></td>     
    <td>
      text that can so on and on and on...<br/>
      more text<br/>
      even more.<br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I'd love to do it that way. But this is part of a bigger piece of work and so table1 has to stay due to the current structure. I can only change stuff directly to do with table2.

Comment: Then it's not possible to stretch the table 100%.

Comment: Darn. Ok, back to the drawing board. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible to stretch the td before table1

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the first `<td>` tag (which holds table2) to be `<td height="100%">` ? That way the cell's height is at maximum, not just the table's.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with JavaScript

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td id="td1"> 
      <table bgcolor="red" id="table1"> 
        <tr> 
          <td width="10px" bgcolor="white">s </td> 
          <td width="30px" bgcolor="yellow">s </td> 
        </tr> 
      </table> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
      text that can so on and on and on...</br> 
      more text</br> 
      even more.</br> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table> 
<script> 
    document.getElementById("table1").style.height = document.getElementById("td1").offsetHeight + "px";
</script>
```

Comment: He is talking about sending an email, no js allowed.